# How to create an enum with map as a field in Java?

Tags: java, enums, hashmap

I need to create an enum in Java having a field of the type Map. How do I initialize the map field? Is there a way without creating an anonymous object or using Guava (or similar) library?

```
public enum Day {
  Sunday(new HashMap<>()); // TODO initialize the map

  private Map<String, String> map;

  Day(Map<String, String> paramMap) {
    this.map.putAll(paramMap);
  }

  public getMap() {return map;}
}
```

Comment: suppose you refer this [example](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/46175/java-enum-containing-a-hash-map-for-look-up)

Comment: @RajithPemabandu That example is a bit different. I don't need a commong map, but a different map for each of the enum values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the key and value of the map are both `String`, you can make the constructor take a varargs and let it build the map for you:

```
public enum Day {
    SUNDAY("Foo", "Fooz",
           "Bar", "Barz",
           "Hello", "Hi");

    private final Map<String, String> map;

    Day(String... keysAndValues) {
        if ((keysAndValues.length & 1) != 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("keysAndValues has odd size: " + Arrays.toString(keysAndValues));
        this.map = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < keysAndValues.length; i += 2) {
            if (keysAndValues[i] == null || keysAndValues[i + 1] == null)
                throw new NullPointerException();
            if (this.map.put(keysAndValues[i], keysAndValues[i + 1]) != null)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("keysAndValues has duplicate key named '" + keysAndValues[i] + "': " + Arrays.toString(keysAndValues));
        }
    }

    public Map<String, String> getMap() {
        return this.map;
    }

}
```

If you print the map for `SUNDAY`, e.g. `System.out.println(Day.SUNDAY.getMap())`, you get:

```
{Bar=Barz, Hello=Hi, Foo=Fooz}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how it could be done with jdk8 and using functional interface

```
import java.util.Map;

public interface MapProducer<K,V> {

  Map<K,V> getMap();

}
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public enum EnumWithMap {
    //empty map
    TEST1(HashMap::new),
    //default map
    TEST2(EnumWithMap::getDefMap),
    //enum instance map
    TEST3(()->{
        Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("key1","val1");
        return map;
    })
    ;

    private final Map<String,String> map;

    EnumWithMap(MapProducer<String,String> mapProducer) {
        this.map = Collections.unmodifiableMap(mapProducer.getMap());
    }

    private static Map<String,String> getDefMap(){
        Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("keyDef","valDef");
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
    }

    public Map<String, String> getMap() {
        return map;
    }
}
```

$Result of foreach Loop:

```
for(EnumWithMap en:EnumWithMap.values())System.out.println(en.getMap());
```

will be:

```
{}
{keyDef=valDef}
{key1=val1}
```